# Prevent Screen Timeout with Adobe AIR for Mobile on Android and iOS

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air

I have a pure AS3 app that I'm deploying to both Android and iOS. In some cases I need the screen to not turn off for 60+ seconds. Is there a way to do this with AIR for mobile?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

i used

```
// no dimming
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
```

to disable the screen timeout for my app.
don't know if you can switch this on and off while the app is running?!

only tested this on android ... but should work on iOS too.

Comment: I found that you also need to adjust the permissions for android for this KEEP_AWAKE to become effective. Add these to your android permissions: 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>

Found this here: http://polygeek.com/4591_air-mobile_keep_awake-for-your-air-mobile-games

Comment: I have the opposite problem. I have SystemIdleMode.NORMAL and it works fine when publishing to the desktop. However, when publishing to IOS it NEVER fires. WTF?
Can't find anything int he documentation that references this.